# MingW32-64 handle Unicode Window DLLs

Tags: qt, mingw

I have a question about QT5 and MingW32-64. I got an API DLL that is compiled with MSVC. This DLL comes with an lib, like usual on Windows. Now compiling the App with QT5/MSVC words perfect. But our compiler is MingW32-64. All the time I tried to send a String to the API DLL I got an error back.
The Error is not really clear, it says "Wrong Parameter"

However this is the code:

```
    QString strSavePath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(fileNames.at(0));

#if defined (WIN32)
    QString rootPath = "\\";
#else
    QString rootPath = "/";
#endif
    SFileToAdd file;
    file.lpszFileName = nullptr;

    //Attention, this differ on MAC And Win32
    const TCHAR *pSavePath = convertToFoxValue(strSavePath);
    const TCHAR *pRootPath = convertToFoxValue(rootPath);

    file.lpszSourceFilePath = pSavePath;
    file.lpszDestinationPath = pRootPath;


    file.bVideoFile = BS_FALSE;

    if(ui->usePath->isChecked()==false){
        file.nSavePath = BS_DONT_SAVE_PATH;
    }else{
        file.nSavePath = BS_WHOLE_PATH;
    }


    int32 res = ::AddFile(file);
    if(res!=0){
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Information"),
                                 tr("Error in AddFile"));
    }

    delete [] pSavePath;
    delete [] pRootPath;
```

The conversion function is:

```
const TCHAR* convertToFoxValue(const QString& strValue)
{

#if defined (WIN32)
    TCHAR *someVar=new TCHAR[strValue.size()+1];
    strValue.toWCharArray(someVar);
    //set last caharacter to null terminator
    someVar[strValue.size()]=L'\0';
    return reinterpret_cast<const TCHAR *>(someVar);
#else
    TCHAR *someVar=new TCHAR[strValue.size()+1];
    QByteArray pass = strValue.toUtf8();
    strcpy(someVar,pass.data());
    return reinterpret_cast<const TCHAR *>(someVar);
#endif

}
```

To submit hard links like

```
    file.lpszSourceFilePath = L"D:\\datapart.pdf";
    file.lpszDestinationPath = L"\\";
```

is also not working. So iam totally confuse. Everything is compile with the _UNICODE flag.
Is there a problem with MinGW and null terminated widestrings? Or do MingW generally work with UNCIDOE settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who have the same problems. Check your header files about defines with MSVC
With me it was

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma pack(push, 1) 
#endif
```

I have changed it to

```
//#ifdef _MSC_VER
//No padding
#ifdef WIN32
#pragma pack(push, 1) 
#endif
```

So also MingW knows now the structur padding and it works now very well. Nothing about C/C++ DLLs or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Calling libraries compiled with another compiler is not a very good idea, especially in C++.
If you want to use Qt from MinGW-w64 then it's best to use a Qt build with the same compiler.

Comment: My question was not a relegion question. If MingW is a compiler that cannot deal with MSVC DLLs then I think is had never become this state. So my issue is something about the MingW usage / special that every compiler has.

Comment: @IFThenElse: Mixing `C` dlls of different compilers is fine, but the same is not true for `C++` dlls.